# Access a host on the same LAN with different ip subnet settings

Tags: windows, networking, static-routes

I'm looking for some help with a route add command. I have a printer that was moved to a different office branch that I'm trying to connect to. It is configured with a static IP which is incorrect for the network it is now plugged in to. Here's the details:

Computer IP: 192.168.101.243
Printer IP:  192.168.100.23

The route command I have used previously was used for setting up a new wirless router, and set up the routing table so that the local network card (192.168.101.243) was able to route packets to the device set on a different subnet (192.168.100.23) as long as you knew what the IP address was. Am I crazy or is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two assumptions:

1. The printer is connected to the same physical network but was assigned the wrong ip address for the subnet.
2. You're using a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 (/24).

If the above assumptions are true then simply add another ip address to your NIC (the host you're trying to connect to the printer from) in the same subnet as the mis-assigned printer. So, if the printer is assigned 192.168.100.23 then assign 192.168.100.24 to your host. You should then be able to connect to the printer.

Comment: Correct on both assumptions. I will try your idea later on today. Great idea, sounds like it should work.

Comment: Glad to help...